# calendar does not show

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

Implemented fullcalendar on a HTML5-jquery website.
Nicely integrated the required files on the server.
Added the css and js relations on the crucial HTML file, which is then supposed to show a calendar...

But nothing shows. Also the navigation dropdown on that page (using jquery...) does not drop down anymore.

As the site already uses (on all files) the jquery version 1.11.2 for the navigation and other items, I, nonetheless, implemented the fullcallendar required jquery files, which seem to use version 2.2.3. of jquery.

Most probably the conflict, or reason why fullcalendar does not show, occurs bcause a conflict arises when various versions of jquery are trying to be loaded.

How do I go about this?
It looks rather impossible to change the jquery version for the original files (already tried, didn't work...) 
But the extra version for fullcalendar most probably prohibits it to show any form of calendar.

Could somebody point me in the right direction, please...

Regards,
Ben

Comment: [No conflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)?

Comment: _How do I go about this?_ You should probably look at the console to check for Javascript errors. Without that we'll just be guessing. Like this guess: Do you have [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) ?

Comment: Please show your file placement. Add you fullcalendar js as the last included js file.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many things.... it may be a simple omission or mistake.

What I did wrong, was the use of referers in the Google Developers Console.
In the second field, after API key, the website referer(s) need to be filled in.
You need to use the right syntax for this.

A wildcard * can be used to get a better solution for several websites and subdomains. Use the URL without "http://" and use a forward slash at the back.
Example 1: mywebsite.org/

For subdomains use a wildcard:
Example 2: *.mywebsite.org/

Or if the website is in a subdirectory:
Example 3: mywebsite.org/*

Correcting this, made it work for me.
And I know I should be ashamed, but that is also why i give it as my working solution, so others can benefit from it.

Thanks for trying to help...